# Can the finite morphism from Noether Normalization be interpreted as a projection?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-curves, projective-geometry

I feel a bit stupid about this question, but I feel an urge to get to know more about this!

Let $R = k[t_0,\ldots,t_n]/I$ where $I \trianglelefteq k[t_0,\ldots,t_n]$ is a homogeneous ideal and such that $X = \operatorname{Proj}(R)$ is a projective $k$-scheme of pure dimension 1.

Given a graded finite ring map $\phi:k[x_0,x_1] \hookrightarrow R$, say from the Noether normalization lemma:

1. is it possible to find an (graded) isomorphism $R \to k[\phi(x_0),\phi(x_1),s_2\ldots,s_n]/J$?
2. does a finite ring map $\phi': k[\phi(x_0),\phi(x_1)] \hookrightarrow k[\phi(x_0),\phi(x_1),s_2\ldots,s_n]/J$ correspond geometrically to the projection onto the first two coordinates
   $$X \to \mathbb{P}_k^1 ,\quad (a_0:a_1:\ldots:a_n) \mapsto (a_0:a_1)?$$

Thanks in advance for any helpful comment on this!

Comment: I think you need to assume that $x_0,x_1$ are linear forms. (This is always possible if $k$ is infinite.) For instance, take $R = k[t_0,t_1]$ and $A = k[t_0^2,t_1]$.